# SSIS Foreach Loop process only files that weren't processed yet

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, dts

I'm developing a SSIS 2012 DTS, it must ETL data from csv to DB.

csv files will be provided every day, the date it's published will be available on the filename: `filename_YYMMDD.csv`.

Of cource it can't process the same file more than once so that data don't duplicate on DB. The issue is that I can't delete or rename files as I process them. I must process files I haven't yet and leave old ones alone.

I'm thinking on using a log table to store the date of files as I process them. In the begining of the FLC, I query DB for the date of current file. If the date isn't found on log table, FLC runs the ETL. If the date is found, FLC skips to next file.

Is it possible? Should I do it with a Script Task? How can I send a `continue` command from the Script Task to the FLC loop? Or can I do it somehow with a Execute SQL Task?

Comment: Of course you can do it with an Execute SQL task.  There is no need to send a continue command, the ForEach loop will go to the next file when all the tasks inside it have completed.

Comment: I mean, after the EST, if it is identified that file was already processed, the FLC must stop current iteration and start the next one, instead of executing it till the end. The continue command I talk is equivalent of a `continue` in C loops.

Comment: In your question you state:  ` In the begining of the FLC, I query DB for the date of current file. If the date isn't found on log table, FLC runs the ETL.`   So again I say, you don't need a continue.   After a file is processed, it will automatically go to the next.  It will again check to see if that file is already processed, and if so, skip it and go to the next, and keep doing that until there are no more files to process.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The proper english word should be skip and not continue. I was just thinking on how loops work in C lol, the C keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly that using a log table for all the files I successfully processed. Make sure that you are doing this in a transaction where you update the log table after the csv file is processed. You may find it handy to include, in the log table, the number of rows processed and how long it took to process the file.

Comment: Great idea! But how to do it? I'm using a Data Flow Task, starting with a Flat File Source and inserting to DB with a OLE DB Destination. How can I know the amount of records it inserted and how long it took?

Comment: You can use a rowcount transformation to get the number of rows that were just processed. What I did was read in the rows into a table and then passed in the file name to a proc (SQL Task) which would decide, by checking the log table, if this table had been processed (in which case it did nothing) or had not been processed (in which case it processed the rows.4) In SQL Server procs you can use @@rowcount and select getdate() before and after processing to see how long something took.

Comment: Is 'rowcount transformation' a SSIS component? I can't find it in SSDT 2012.

Comment: Hi, Its in every version of SSIS that I know of: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141136.aspx